# Why an exception is thrown when I set a property of a NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, selector

I am making an app that lets the user create playlists and put strings in them. I am doing this using Core Data. This is the data model:

[image]

Pretty self-explanatory. I then generate the managed object subclasses of the two entities:

```
extension Playlists {

    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var utterrances: NSOrderedSet?

}

class Playlists: NSManagedObject {
    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    }
}

extension Utterance {

    @NSManaged var string: String?
    @NSManaged var playlist: Playlists?

}

class Utterance: NSManagedObject {

    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    }
}
```

Now I have empty playlists in the database. I was writing code to let the user add new strings into the playlist. I do this by letting the user select a playlist from a table view controller. When the user selects a playlist, the string (stored in `stringToAdd`, see below) is added to the selected playlist.

Here is the code in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let playlistToAddTo = playlists[indexPath.row]
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Playlist", inManagedObjectContext: dataContext)
    let utterance = Utterance(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: dataContext)
    utterance.string = stringToAdd
    utterance.playlist = playlistToAddTo
    dataContext.saveData()
}
```

When I click the table view cell, it crashes with this:

```
X[1541:108724] -[X.Playlists setString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d01ab70
2016-02-07 17:34:10.520 iEnglish[1541:108724] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[X.Playlists setString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d01ab70'
```

Note: I replaced all the occurrences of my app's name with `X` because I don't want to disclose it.

Apparently this line of code causes the error:

```
utterance.string = stringToAdd
```

I added some print statements to verify that:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print(stringToAdd) // #1
    let playlistToAddTo = playlists[indexPath.row]
    print(playlistToAddTo.name) // #2
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Playlist", inManagedObjectContext: dataContext)
    print("entity object created") // #3
    let utterance = Utterance(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: dataContext)
    print("new utterance created") // #4
    utterance.string = stringToAdd
    print("string added") // #5
    utterance.playlist = playlistToAddTo
    print("playlist added") // #6
    dataContext.saveData()
    print("data saved") // #7
}
```

And only #1 ~ #4 is printed.

Why is this happening? How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a wrong entity description.

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Playlist", inManagedObjectContext: dataContext)
let utterance = Utterance(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: dataContext)
```

You're creating an entity description **Playlist** and then an object **Utterance** which does not match the entity description and has no property `string`

Comment: I am kinda confused. If the entity is wrong, how can the new utterance object be created without error? I.e. Why the fourth print statement gets executed?

Comment: The entity description is just an identifier. It does not check the properties while the managed object is created.

Comment: Now I understand! Thanks again!